# Android Live Streaming using MJPG on HTTP or RTSP protocol

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming, esp32, arduino-ide

I purchased ESP32 camera and installed code on ESP32 camera using Arduino IDE. I am able to see the feed on chrome and VLC. I am writing an android app which used Android MediaPlayer and Surface View to view the live streaming video. But in the android app I am not able to view the stream.

In the ESP32 Camera, I tried with both HTTP and RTSP protocol. In both the cases, facing the following error in media player

```
12-01 09:57:58.446 20282 20282 E Cam_VideoStreamPreview: Mediaplayer info :: what = 701, extra = 0
12-01 09:57:59.657 20282 20297 E MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
12-01 09:57:59.657 20282 20282 E MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

#### **Media Player logic in code**

```
//private const val STREAM_URI = "http://192.168.1.11/stream"
//private const val STREAM_URI = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
//private const val STREAM_URI = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
//private const val STREAM_URI = ""
//private const val STREAM_URI = "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4"
//private const val STREAM_URI = "http://192.168.1.8:8080/Downloads/Sintel.mp4"
private const val STREAM_URI = "rtsp://192.168.1.11:8554/mjpeg/1"

val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
            setAudioAttributes(
                    AudioAttributes.Builder()
                            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                            .build()
            )
            setDataSource(STREAM_URI)
        }
```

I then do `prepare` and then in that callback I will call the `start` method from mediaplayer.

#### Content Type Http Response

In the ESP32 camera, we use HTTP Live Streaming protocol. Output format will be in MJPG format. Initial header response will have `Content-Type` as `multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=123456789000000000000987654321`. All the chunked response will have `Content-Type` as `image/jpeg`

```
*   Trying 192.168.1.11...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.1.11 (192.168.1.11) port 80 (#0)
> GET /stream HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.11
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=123456789000000000000987654321
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
<
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=123456789000000000000987654321
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 6503
```

I have the following doubts

1. I checked the supported media requirements from android (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#network ). They support HLS and RTSP protocol. Whether the `Content-Type` would be a problem here?
2. Whether there are any alternatives to `android media player`. Can I read the chunks myself and display in android? Whether such thing is possible in android?

Comment: did you find an answer?